# Spring Boot Actuator/Micrometer Metrics Disable Some

Tags: metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

Is there a way to turn off some of the returned metric values in Actuator/Micrometer? Looking at them now I'm seeing around 1000 and would like to whittle them down to a select few say 100 to actually be sent to our registry.

Comment: Maybe Meter Filters could help? http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meter_filters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Meter filters](http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_meter_filters) can help in 3 ways that have been discussed with the Micrometer slack channel:

1. Disabling metrics
2. Combining dimensions
3. High cardinality capping filter

Micrometer comes with the first type of **meter filter** built in. It also support hierarchical enabling/disabling similar to how logging works (As in if have meter like `my.request.total` and `my.request.latency` you can disable all metrics that start with `my.request`.

I've implemented my own example of a **combining filter** which is useful if you have a metrics with high cardinality and want to combine them in new dimensions. Take for example you have a dimension on status codes, this lets you combine 200, 201, 203 response codes as a tag `2xx`. This is similar to Netflix Spectator '[placeholder](https://github.com/Netflix/spectator/blob/master/docs/ext/placeholders.md)' support. I would love to contribute that code upstream, but currently it is pretty custom, so it would need some work to make it generally usable.

The last type for catching **high cardinality** dimensions, hasn't been created yet, but would exist as a safety valve ensuring that if a metric can potentially have a high number of tag value, it will count the number of unique tags and once a max value is hit, either disable or combine the additional tags into a common bucket, so that value doesn't explode and potentially overwhelm your monitoring (or cost you lots of $$$, if paying per-metric)

Comment: I guess as a follow up to this question, I was able to change the global meter filter by using an @PostConstruct but this didn't feel right. Is there a better way or a way of overriding the Globabl Registry bean?

Comment: Use a `MeterRegistryCustomizer` like so: ```@Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> customizer(
            @Value("${spring.application.name}") String applicationName) {
        return (registry) -> registry.config().commonTags("application", applicationName);
    }```

Will be easier to read in a new questions.

Comment: Is there any way to remove specific tags/labels from metrics before publishing metric

Comment: @omjego Ask this as a new question. As a quick answer yes: http://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_transforming_metrics. See 'ignoreTags'

Answer (score 30):

Let me elaborate on the answer posted by [checketts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970308/checketts) with a few examples. You can enable/disable certain metrics in your `application.yml` like this ([Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.customizing.per-meter-properties)):

```
management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      tomcat: true
      jvm: false
      process: false
      hikaricp: false
      system: false
      jdbc: false
      http: false
      logback: true
```

Or in code by defining a MeterFilter bean:

```
@Bean
public MeterFilter meterFilter() {
    return new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public MeterFilterReply accept(Meter.Id id) {
            if(id.getName().startsWith("tomcat.")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            if(id.getName().startsWith("jvm.")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            if(id.getName().startsWith("process.")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            if(id.getName().startsWith("system.")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            return MeterFilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This post is a few years old, and may now be obsolete. The syntax changed in spring boot 2.x

Answer (score 6):

The property naming in [Mzzl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097060/1763035) has changed in Spring Boot 2. For example, to disable the JVM metrics it's now:

```
management.metrics.binders.jvm.enabled=false
```

See [this class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricsAutoConfiguration.java#L90) for the other options. The Spring team have refactored yet again in `2.1.x` and those inner factory bean classes are now lifted out into standalone files but the property naming remains the same as `2.0.x`.