# How to create a metric in Spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How to create a metric in SpringBoot2.1.4.RELEASE?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, a bean of type [`MeterRegistry`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.5/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.html) will be created. Once autowired, this allows you to create several metrics, such as counters, gauges and metrics. Each of these have a fluent builder you can use that allows you to set them up, for example:

#### Counters

A `Counter` can be used for simple incrementing metrics, for example, the amount of times a method has been called.

```
Counter customCounter = Counter
    .builder("my.custom.metric.counter")
    .register(meterRegistry);
```

By using `customCounter.increment()` you can increase the value.

#### Gauges

A `Gauge` on the other hand is a dynamic/live value that should be measured directly. An example of this is the size of a connection pool:

```
 Gauge
      .builder("my.custom.metric.gauge", () -> connectionPool.size())
      .register(meterRegistry);
```

The builder allows you to pass a `Supplier` to measure whatever you want.

#### Timers

As the name mentions, this can be used to measure the time it takes do something, for example:

```
Timer customTimer = Timer
     .builder("my.custom.metric.timer")
     .register(meterRegistry);
```

By using the `customTimer.record(() -> myMethod())`, you can add a metric about how long it takes to invoke `myMethod()`.

---

You should be able to access these metrics when running the application. If you want to see them through HTTP, you can enable the metrics endpoint like this:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=metrics # Enable metrics endpoint
```

After that, you should be able to visit http://localhost:8080/actuator to see the list of enabled endpoints, which should contain http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics.

This API should return a list of available metrics, which can be accessed as http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/my.custom.metric.counter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i have a question yet,how to disable a metric?

Comment: @User9527 That has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48451381/1915448

Comment: This will really help!

Comment: Is It possible to create metric in MeterRegistry metric without Autowire?

Answer (score 0):

You can use micrometer:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This will give you the end-point: `/actuator/prometheus`