# Disable spring integration metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have the spring boot application exposing actuator/prometheus endpoint for monitoring,

I want to turn off metrics for spring integration components, keeping for http requests only.

I've tried disabling it in configuration according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#_per_meter_properties)  in this way:

```
management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      spring:
        integration: false
```

That did not work for me.

Could you help me?

Comment: Did you try it with a meter filter? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097060/13211030

Comment: What do you mean by **spring integration components**?
Please look also at [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#_per_meter_properties)

Comment: @JadenKorr  The application is built using spring integration flows starting from http inbound gateway.

Comment: See my answer. It seems there is a confuse with migration from properties to YAML.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look into [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#_per_meter_properties) again!

> In addition to `MeterFilter` beans, it’s also possible to apply a limited set of customization on a per-meter basis using properties. Per-meter customizations apply to any all meter IDs that start with the given name. For example, the following will disable any meters that have an ID starting with `example.remote`:

```
management.metrics.enable.example.remote=false
```

But your YAML config is slightly different in regards `spring.integration` pattern to match. I think it has to be like this:

```
management:
  metrics:
    enable:
      spring.integration: false
```