# How to disable some of the metrics of the actuator for prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I am using spring boot actuator (Spring Boot 2) to monitor the state of the application. Prometheus collects metrics. It calls endpoint actuator/prometheus. But there are quite a lot of metrics there. Is there any way to disable some of the metrics for prometheus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097060/325224